# Framelayout behaviour

Tags: android, android-framelayout

What I know about the framelayout is that, Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top. It's on the official documentation page as well.

I have seen it behave that way too but from the past few experiences I have noticed that the child at the bottom of the stack are also accessible for example

```
<framelayout>
<button1>  // should not be accessible
<button2>  // should be accessible

</framelayout>
```

but I can click button 2 also, how does framlayout actually behaves this is the only one layout I can't get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have noticed that the child at the bottom of the stack are also accessible

Touch events go to the widget that is on the top of the Z-axis at the X/Y coordinates of the touch event. `RelativeLayout` has the same effect.

> `<button1>  // should be accessible <button2>  // should not be accessible`

That is incorrect. Later children of a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` are higher on the Z-axis. Hence, `button2` will float over top of `button1`, where they overlap. If `button1` is visible, the user can tap that visible portion and `button1` will receive that touch event. `button2`, since it is on top of the stack of widgets in the `FrameLayout`, will always be visible and will always be eligible for touch events in its visible area.

Comment: sorry my mistake button 2 should be accessible and button 1 shouldn't but I want to know if it is in stack why do the bottom child recieves the touch event.

Comment: @MeraClientChorhai: As I wrote, "touch events go to the widget that is on the top of the Z-axis at the X/Y coordinates of the touch event". Hence, whatever part of `button1` is *visible* can be touched, and it will receive that touch event.